# Fix event problem after creating new elements?

Tags: javascript

When I click on the item it shows the clicked element but after creating a new item it's not working for the new items.

I know this is happening for the first **items selector** `let items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');`, it just holds the elements when page loads after creating new Items it does not affects the items selector. But I need to fix it. If I create new items it should work for all items (old and new both).

```js
//for some stuff..
let

    items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

items.forEach( (elm) =>{
  elm.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
      console.log(
        elm.innerText
      );
  })
});


//create new one
let

  btn = document.querySelector('button'),
  app = document.querySelector('.app-view'),
  dataId = 0;


btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  dataId++;
  
  let 
    
    newItem = document.createElement('div');
  
  newItem.className = 'item';
  newItem.innerHTML = `I am from planet ${dataId}`;
  app.insertAdjacentElement ('beforeend', newItem);
  
});
```

```css
.item{
  padding: .25rem 1rem;
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  color: purple;
  user-select:none;
  
}

.item:hover{
  cursor: default;
  border: 1px dotted #000;
}

.default-item{
  color: #007bff;
}

button{
  position: fixed;
  top: 1rem;
  right: 1rem;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="app-view">
  <div class="item default-item">Default Item</div>
</div>

<button>
  Create New
</button>
```

Comment: you forgot to add the `eventListener` to the newly added `.items`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using event delegation:

```js
const itemContainer = document.querySelector('.app-view');

itemContainer.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('item') {
    // do stuff
  }
});
```

Note that this must use [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) (the clicked element), not [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) (the element to which the listener is attached).

You can find more info in this blog post: [How JavaScript Event Delegation Works](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)

> Event delegation allows you to avoid adding event listeners to specific nodes;  instead, the event listener is added to one parent.  That event listener analyzes bubbled events to find a match on child elements

Comment: But this is sometimes so tuff to reach the targeted element like this situation...

<div class="wrapper"> <div class="TARGET"> <div class="inner"> <div class="nothing"></div> </div>  </div> </div>

Comment: @Md.Tahazzot I'm not sure I understand that example, but yes, this method does require the target elements to have a common ancestor. But that ancestor can always be something like `document.querySelector('#your-app-root')` or even simply `document.body`.

Answer (score 1):

An event listener needs to be attached to each `newItem` when it is created.

I've moved this in to a function so that the code can be reused.

```js
//for some stuff..
let items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

items.forEach((elm) => {
  bindClickEvent(elm); // Attach event to existing items
});

function bindClickEvent(elm) {
  elm.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(
      elm.innerText
    );
  })
}

//create new one
let btn = document.querySelector('button'),
    app = document.querySelector('.app-view'),
    dataId = 0;


btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  dataId++;

  let newItem = document.createElement('div');

  newItem.className = 'item';
  newItem.innerHTML = `I am from planet ${dataId}`;
  app.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', newItem);
  
  bindClickEvent(newItem);  // Attach event to new item

});
```

```css
.item {
  padding: .25rem 1rem;
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  color: purple;
  user-select: none;
}

.item:hover {
  cursor: default;
  border: 1px dotted #000;
}

.default-item {
  color: #007bff;
}

button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 1rem;
  right: 1rem;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="app-view">
  <div class="item default-item">Default Item</div>
</div>

<button>
  Create New
</button>
```

Comment: If you want a single event listener for new and old items, [Lionel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61731818/746736) would be better suited.

Comment: The first one is not so much convenient as your answer. This is more useful and I learn from it Thanks.